# linux command to remove or replace whitespaces and special characters

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can get `rename ' ' _ *` to work to remove the first whitespace, but when I try something like `rename 's/ /_/g' *` nothing happens. Ideally I would like a command that can rename a file and remove all whitespaces and special characters to leave only letters and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

something line this may be, *extracts only letters and numbers*

```
echo "file with spaces here.txt" | sed -e 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/ /g' | tr ' ' '_'
```

for all files in the directory something like

```
for f in *;
do
   newName=$( echo "$f" | sed -e 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z ]/ /g' | tr ' ' '_' );
   mv "$f" "$newName";
done
```